# SQL - match last two characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a small mysql database with a column which has format of a field as following:

```
x_1_1,
x_1_2,
x_1_2,
x_2_1,
x_2_12,
x_3_1,
x_3_2,
x_3_11,
```

I want to extra the data where it matches last '_1'. So if I run a query on above sample dataset, it would return

```
x_1_1,
x_2_1,
x_3_1,
```

This should not return x_2_12 or x_3_11.

I tried like '%_1' but it returns x_2_12 and x_3_11 as well.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple method is the `right()` function:

```
select t.*
from t
where right(field, 2) = '_1';
```

You can use `like` but you need to escape the `_`:

```
where field like '%$_1' escape '$'
```

Or use regular expressions:

```
where field regexp '_1$'
```

Answer (score 1):

The underscore character has special significance in a LIKE clause. It acts as a wildcard and represent one single character. So you would have to escape it with a backslash:

```
LIKE '%\_1'
```

RIGHT does the job too, but it requires that you provide the proper length for the string being sought and is thus less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Duh, I found the answer.

Use RIGHT (col_name, 2) = '_1'

Thank you!